# Перестановки в массиве: минимальное число попарных перестановок, чтобы из одного массива другой получить и возможно ли это

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть две строки из А={0,1,2,3}*
Нужно выяснить можно ли одну из них получить из другой несколькими бинарными перестановками и найти количество таких перестановок.

1. Насколько я понимаю получить одну из другой - это узнать,является
   ли первая анаграммой другой?
2. Как можно реализовать "найти количество таких перестановок"?

Comment: Если повторений нет и одна строка является перестановкой другой строки (сортировкой легко проверить), то минимальное кол-во попарных обменов, которые одну строку в другую превращают, можно найти, используя [`number_of_swaps()` функцию](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2989341/4279)

Comment: В этом,насколько я понимаю, и заключается сложность, т. к * означает строки произвольной длины из данных символов(0,1,2,3)

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Minimum number of swaps needed to change Array 1 to Array 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2987605/4279) и [Counting the swaps required to convert one permutation into another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7797540/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы узнать сколько *минимально* попарных обменов (swaps) букв необходимо, чтобы превратить одну входную строку в другую, когда буквы могут повторяться, можно найти все возможные перестановки индексов, которые из одной строки делают другую (`get_permutations()`), а затем посчитать для каждой получившейся перестановки кол-во обменов, которые она требует, используя [`number_of_swaps(permutation)` функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989341/4279), и выбрать минимум кол-ва обменов:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def get_permutations(a, b):
    """Generate all permutations that convert *a* sequence into *b* sequence."""
    positions = defaultdict(list) # letter -> "list of positions in *a*"
    for position, letter in enumerate(a):
        positions[letter].append(position)

    # generate all permutations choosing all available indices at each position
    #NOTE: using product() is not very efficient here but it is simple
    multiset = (positions[letter] for letter in b)
    for permutation in itertools.product(*multiset):
        if len(permutation) == len(set(permutation)):
            yield permutation
```

Эта функция ожидает, что можно `a` строку в `b` превратить, то есть выполнено любое из:

```
# assert that we can permute *a* string into *b*
assert len(a) == len(b) and all(a.count(c) == b.count(c) for c in set(a))
assert Counter(a) == Counter(b)
assert sorted(a) == sorted(b) # each of the 3 assertions is enough by itself
```

`get_permutations(a, b)` возвращает списки индексов (перестановки), такие что `a` превращается в `b`:

```
# assert that *permutation* permutes *a* into *b*
assert [a[p] for p in permutation] == list(b) # each of the 2 is enough by itself
assert all(c == a[permutation[i]] for i, c in enumerate(b))
```

Каждый вызов к `get_permutations()` генерирует `m[c1]! * m[c2]! ...`  перестановок (permutation), где `m[ci]` (multiplicity) это сколько раз буква `ci` повторяется во входном слове, а `!` это факториал. Например, для `TTAGGG` строки `2! * 1! * 3! == 12` перестановок генерируется.

Чтобы минимальное число попарных обменов найти:

```
def minimal_number_of_swaps(a, b):
    """Find the minimal number of swaps to convert *a* into *b* sequence."""
    return min(map(number_of_swaps, get_permutations(a, b)))
```

Пример:

```
assert list(get_permutations('kamal', 'amalk')) == [(1,2,3,4,0), (3,2,1,4,0)]
assert minimal_number_of_swaps('kamal', 'amalk') == 3
```

Здесь `(1,2,3,4,0)` перестановка требует `4` попарных обменов, чтобы получить `(0,1,2,3,4)` (единичная перестановка), а `(3,2,1,4,0)` перестановка требует только `3`:

```
(3,2,1,4,0) -> # меняем 0,3 пару индексов
(0,2,1,4,3) -> # меняем 1,2 пару индексов
(0,1,2,4,3) -> # меняем 3,4 пару индексов
(0,1,2,3,4)
```

Та же перестановка, но в виде букв:

```
01234    01243    02143    32140
kamal -> kamla -> kmala -> amalk
```

ещё:

```
yoda_words   = "in the force strong you are".split()
normal_words = "you are strong in the force".split()
assert minimal_number_of_swaps(normal_words, yoda_words) == 5
```

здесь буквами являются целые слова, и так как все слова уникальны, то можно было бы использовать [более простую `get_permutation()` функцию, так как только одна перестановка возможна. `number_of_swaps(permutation)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989341/4279) работает, подсчитывая сколько циклов присутствует в перестановке—результат равен `len(permutation) - ncycles`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Да.
2. Самый простой вариант - перебором всех возможных перестановок для тех элементов, которые стоят на разных местах.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за развернутый экспертный ответ по теме вопроса.