# Динамическое программирование и сортировка

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день. Я понимаю, что это выглядит как просьба сделать работу за меня, но не знаю, как разубедить :)

У меня есть задача - последовательность N чисел, и вопрос стоит так - сколько наименьшее число обменов элементов последовательности, которые надо сделать, чтобы она стала сортированной. Мне кажется, что ее можно решить динамическим программированием.

Как я понимаю, динамическое программирование - это разбиение задачи на подзадачу поменьше с использованием ее решения, но никак не могу сообразить, какую именно подзадачу я должен решить.

Если это подзадача - сколько обменов для N-1 элементов, так ведь очередной может быть таким, что придется всю последовательность перетасовать, чтоб его на место поставить? А как я понимаю, для любой последовательности больше N-1 обмена не потребуется? А тут может быть так, что для меньшей - N-2 обмена, и еще для этого элемента N-1 - значит, это не подходит?

Или как подзадачу брать расстановку последовательности без, скажем, наибольшего элемента? А потом как его на место поставить - просто последовательностью обменов до конца? Непохоже, потому что, может, было бы выгоднее убрать какой-то другой элемент?

Задача не учебная, придумал сам для себя, чтоб разобраться с ДП. Или я придумал ерунду и ДП для этой задачи вообще не применимо?

Словом, был бы благодарен за подталкивание на правильный путь.

И еще - по книжкам читая, кажется, что для каждой задачи авторы придумывают какой-то свой способ, и нет никакого общего принципа, как динамическое программирование применять. Если повезет - придумаешь, а не повезет - значит, никак? Неужели нет какого-то формального подхода?

Comment: @AlexKrass, дано, `[2,1]`, нужно получить `[1,2]`, не на своих местах **2** элемента, но обмен нужен один

Comment: для последовательности в N элементов понадобиться на больше N-1 обменов. Алгоритм такой - в массиве находим максимальный элемент и, если он не на первом месте - обмениваем. Потом рассматриваем подмассив от следующего элемента до конца. Решать задачу будет за N-квадрат.

Comment: Да, для каждой задачи действительно придумывается свой способ, поскольку динамическое программирование лежит выше них по абстракции. Оно определяет только "верхушку" алгоритма на основе придуманных деталей, связанных между собой определённым образом.

Comment: @KoVadim А можно это считать динамическим программированием? Просто это я сразу нашел, но подумалось - а если есть какие-то хитрые расстановки, которые могут сделать быстрее? Не в общем случае, понятно.

Comment: @KoVadim, согласен с Вашим вариантом, а вот я походу люблю перемудрить с решением.

Comment: @D-side Тогда прямо грустно как-то... Это уже какой-то высший пилотаж получается.

Comment: ДП применимо для любой задачи. Но не для любой оно будет эффективным. Вы неверно понимаете суть ДП. Это не просто разбить задачу на подзадачи, а нужно чтобы из оптимальности решения подзадачи следовала оптимальность решения полной задачи. То есть не любое приходящее в голову разбиение на подзадачи будет ДП. Общая же схема "выдумывания" ДП для задачи точно такая же, как для задач на математическую индукцию. По сути это одно и то же.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Перестановки в массиве: минимальное число попарных перестановок, чтобы из одного массива другой получить и возможно ли это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575794/23044)

Comment: Насколько помню, это называется *оптимальной сортировкой* (и рассмотрено в т.3 "Сортировка и поиск" известной книги Д. Кнута)

Answer (score 1):

Задачу можно решить таким путём

1. Получить отсортированную последовательность.
2. Последовательно обменять каждый элемент исходной выборки с соответствующим элементом по ранжиру.
   Таким образом, нужно не более N-1 обменов.

Но это не ДП.

ДП требует формирования массива классов перестановок 0, 1,...,N-1 (класс 0 - отсортированная выборка, класс m - выборка, упорядочиваемая минимум за m обменов) на основе N! возможных перестановок. Индекс каждой перестановки формируется из позиций элементов в отсортированной последовательности. В массиве запоминается его класс m и опционально - пара элементов, обмен которых ведёт в класс m-1.

Для запуска ДП также необходима отсортированная последовательность, поскольку классы формируются от младшего к старшему.

Алгоритм громоздкий, но даёт минимальное количество требуемых обменов. Что и требовалось по условию.