# Опять сортировка перестановками

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Я уже спрашивал здесь, как решить [задачу с сортировкой перестановками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600261/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Там решалось все просто, без всякого программирования.

Я решил ее усложнить, и теперь вообще никак не соображу, как ее решить. Допустим, как обычно, что есть массив из N чисел от 1 до N, который мы сортируем. Но теперь можно обменивать только соседние числа.

Уже никак не пойму, верно ли я посчитал, что надо просто для каждого числа сложить количество мест, на которое оно отстоит от своего места в отсортированном массиве, и просуммировать?

А теперь сама задача - найти наихудший вариант начального расположения чисел. Казалось бы просто - это обратная последовательность. А если представить при этом, что нам все равно, какая сортировка будет - от 1 до N или от N до 1 - то как нам найти это наихудшее начальное расположение чисел?

Словом, конечная задача звучит так: имеем числа от 1 до N. Можно менять местами только два соседних элемента массива. Нас устраивает и сортировка в порядке возрастания, и в порядке убывания - все равно, что мы получим. Вопрос - каково наихудшее начальное расположение чисел, т.е. требующее максимального количества обменов? И сколько таких обменов требуется?

Извините, если не очень внятно написал. Как подойти к решению такой задачи?

Comment: Я не могу ее запрограммировать :(, но с точки зрения математики, если не ошибаюсь, вам хватит n(n-1)/4 обменов (деление целочисленное), но как нарисовать наихудшее распределение - что-то не очень представляю. Хотя знаю некоторое его свойство :) - если рассмотреть все пары чисел, то среди них должно быть те же n(n-1)/4 пар, в которых первое число больше второго (или второе больше первого - в зависимости, куда будем упорядочивать).

Comment: @Harry это ж вроде пузырек в чистом виде, или я чего не так понял?

Comment: @rdorn Не в чистом, потому что ему все равно - сортировать по возрастанию или по убыванию. Т.е. критерий сортировки определяется в ее процессе, а не до того.

Answer (score 0):

Не ответ, но размышления. Оформляю как ответ, ибо в комментарий не поместится.

Возьмём оба КОНЕЧНЫХ состояния и местоположение случайного элемента:

```
1 2 3 ... a b с ... x y z
.......R.................
z y x ... c b a ... 3 2 1
```

Где должен располагаться случайный элемент **R** так, чтобы персонально для него удалённость до ближайшего конечного местоположения была наибольшей? очевидно, что для **R** в диапазоне от **z/4** до **3z/4** такое местоположение - любой край, а для остальных- середина. А если всё это немножко обдумать, то станет очевидно, что все элементы (уже все, а не один) можно расположить так, чтобы они отстояли от ближайшего "конечного" места на четверть диапазона (на **z/4**, с точностью до целочисленного деления). Т.е. нижняя граница оценки количества обменов для наихудшего распределения не менее **1/8 * z^2**.

Comment: Я думал так. Но не окажется ли еще хуже, если мы посредине оставим abc? Тогда нам надо будет еще дальше двигать... Впрочем, мне больше интересно ее решить не как математическую задачу, а как ее запрограммировать...

Comment: Не, вроде бы не окажется. Отодвигая от оптимума один элемент, мы вынуждены придвигать другие.